# What encoding is applied to special characters in uploaded filenames?

Tags: php, http, file-upload

Minimal example:

```php
 <?php
    foreach ($_FILES as $f) {
        header('Content-Type: text/plain');
        die("Original filename of uploaded file: " . $f['name']);
    }
?>
<form method=POST enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type=file name=f>
    <input type=submit>
</form>
```

Demo: https://lgms.nl/p/tiny/upload-filename.php
<sup>(source code: https://lgms.nl/p/tiny/upload-filename.php?source)</sup>

Filenames are converted as follows:

- `test space` remains unaltered
- `quote" space` turns into `quote%22 space` (Firefox downloads such a file as `quote space`, silently dropping the `%22` or original quote symbol)
- a newline, such as `new\nline` (where the `\n` is an actual ASCII newline character, not the escape sequence), is converted to `new%0Aline` (Firefox downloads such a file as `new%0Aline`, this time not silently dropping the escaped part)
- the part before any literal backslash seems to be removed, even if that leads to an empty filename

Reading the relevant documentation,

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

I see no mention of any encoding being applied to the filename. There is the ancient magic quotes setting for PHP, but this is not enabled on my server (I added this to the demo page).

Users who try to supply backslashes or newlines can expect that this leads to problems, but quotes in filenames don't seem outlandish to me and I would like to generally just handle this all correctly.

- What encoding is being applied?
- Does this encoding aim to make it safe for passing to `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="VALUE"`? (Not that I would trust implicit encoding to be future-proof... see: magic quotes.)
- How can I retrieve the original filename so that I can apply this encoding manually (explicitly) instead?

Comment: Upon further testing with curl, it seems that the quote escaping is done by Firefox! I was barking up the wrong tree by looking at PHP as the culprit. However, newlines are still swallowed: I can see with `curl --trace` that the newline is literally passed, but it is not reflected in the output. PHP, Apache, or the Nginx proxy swallows it. Perhaps I could tcpdump behind the proxy... either way, if anyone has documentation on what browsers commonly escape and how to get the original filename value...

Comment: I'd expect standard URL-encoding is applied during upload. But the name should then be decoded correctly by php automatically. Are you saying that isn't happening in some cases?

Comment: @ADyson The data does not seem to be fully URL-encoded, neither by curl nor by Firefox, though the tools handle different inputs differently: curl literally uploads a quote whereas Firefox translates it to `%22`; curl literally uploads a newline whereas Firefox translates it to `%0A`; but then neither client translates a space to `%20` so it's not URL encoding. I could apply `urldecode` but I don't know if that will give the correct result in all cases, or might error out (perhaps in a future PHP version) if there is invalid data, such as the unencoded space.

Comment: How are you observing these results? Is it from the content of the $_FILES variable? Or do you have another method? Just do I'm sure exactly what you're reporting

Comment: The part of the multipart request for the file upload will start something like this, `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field"; filename="example.txt"` - not sure any URL-encoding of spaces would be needed here, but double quotes inside the file name surely will need _some_ form of encoding to not break the whole thing.

Comment: _"I could apply urldecode but I don't know if that will give the correct result in all cases, or might error out"_ - that is pretty safe, `urldecode` will decode all percent-encoded sequences it finds, but it is not it's job to "validate" whether any character _is_ URL-encoded. (But it could still mean trouble if you are decoding something a _second_ time, that wasn't supposed to. Maybe a file name _was_ supposed to actually contain `%20` _literally_. Decoding that _again_, would then "falsify" the data.)

Comment: @CBroe Exactly, hence this question

Comment: @ADyson The source code is a handful of lines, shown at the top of this post. You can also try the live demo with the link below that. Indeed I am looking at the `$_FILES` variable. Could you clarify what part is unclear?

Comment: I wasn't sure if you were using another network monitoring tool to see what's inside the request itself, or viewing the what PHP shows you after it's imported and tried to decode that data. The difference could have been important.

Comment: P.S. I can't fully test your demo right now as I'm on Windows, and backslashes and quote marks aren't valid in windows filenames.

Comment: @ADyson It's about what PHP itself shows in `$_FILES[$fieldname]['name']`, I'm not using network monitoring tools here. Just creating a file with e.g. `touch 'one" test'` or `touch "$(echo -ne 'new\nline')"` and then uploading that in the demo.